# Connection reset when using jsch to connect to an sftp server hosted in azure

Tags: java, azure, ssh, azure-storage, jsch

we are currently working with a cloud product that uses JSCH internally to connect to external sftp sources. Im investigating an connection reset exception that we are getting when trying to connect to azure sftp.

Using wireshark i determined that the problem occurs after we send the Client: Key Exchange Init. Establishing the same connection with filezilla we dont have this issue.

comparing the packages from jsch and filezilla i didn't see an obivious issue, but im not an expert on the ssh protocol. im gonna post both requests below if somebody could give me any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

[Request with JSCH (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Se8o.jpg)

[Request with Filezilla (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABoKS.jpg)

[Response with Filezilla (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMrP1.jpg)

See below for the log output:

```
INFO: Connecting to ***** port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-AzureSSH_1.0.0
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: Disconnecting from **** port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

EDIT: following jameses suggestion i got the same result, connection closed but the client request only had the supported algos as payload.
So i tried to replicate the FileZilla request by setting the jsch config regardless if jsch actually supports the algo, i just wanted to see if there is any respone.

But for some reason the connection still gets terminated

[Modified jsch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi6ty.jpg)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i added the log output.  after we send the SSH_MSG_KEXINIT message the server resets the connection. My first idea was there are no matching algos between server and client but looking at the supported algorithms section in the azure docs it should work unless im missing something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-known-issues

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i added the server response when using FileZilla. The thing i noticed (idk if its relevant) On the FileZilla request and the Server response the protocol version includes encryption information thats not the case with the JSch request. And yes im on the lastest version 0.1.55

Comment: There indeed seems to be an overlap for each set of algorithms. I assume the encryption info indicates the agreed algorithm. And it does not happen in JSch instance as the connection is closed. Did you try restricting for example OpenSSH `ssh` to the same set of algorithms as JSch?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I will try with OpenSSH tomorrow and report back. As for the encryption info, i dont think thats the case. If you look at my filezilla request it has the same encryption info before the server even responded with the KeyExchange. And the JSch connection gets terminated after the KeyExchange request that doesn't contain that encryption info.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue - Azure disconnects immediately after sending SSH_MSG_KEXINIT.  I have posted a bounty to hopefully get some more interest in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wanted to post a quick update for anybody that is having the same issue, i opened a similiar question on the microsoft q&a site and looks like it's an issue on the azure side that they are working on fixing for GA [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/713024/connection-to-azure-sftp-doesnt-work-using-jsch.html?childToView=720888#comment-720888)

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  From the MS site it looks like it will be fixed before Azure SFTP goes to production release.  This is exactly what I was looking for - enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the latest comment (from JGiltner62-0227 on 2022-02-18) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/713024/connection-to-azure-sftp-doesnt-work-using-jsch.html I now have a working JSCH implementation.  There are two things that need to change in the source code, both in Session.java.

1. Line 71:

`private byte[] V_C=Util.str2byte("SSH-2.0-JSCH-"+JSch.VERSION); // client version`

needs to change to:

`private byte[] V_C=Util.str2byte("SSH-2.0-JSCH_"+JSch.VERSION); // client version`

(The difference is an underscore instead of a dash after 'JSCH').

2. Line 253:

`byte[] foo=new byte[V_C.length+1];`

`System.arraycopy(V_C, 0, foo, 0, V_C.length);`

`foo[foo.length-1]=(byte)'\n';`

needs to change to

`byte[] foo=new byte[V_C.length+2];`

`System.arraycopy(V_C, 0, foo, 0, V_C.length);`

`foo[foo.length-2]=(byte)0x0D;`

`foo[foo.length-1]=(byte)'\n';`

(the variable 'foo' needs to be V_C.length + 2 instead of +1, and then we insert 0x0D as the second to last byte.)

After making these two changes I confirmed that the library works uploading to Azure SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

From [SSH RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253#section-4.2):

```
   When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
   identification string.  This identification string MUST be

      SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF

   Both the 'protoversion' and 'softwareversion' strings MUST consist of
   printable US-ASCII characters, with the exception of whitespace
   characters and the minus sign (-).  The 'softwareversion' string is
   primarily used to trigger compatibility extensions and to indicate
   the capabilities of an implementation.  The 'comments' string SHOULD
   contain additional information that might be useful in solving user
   problems.  As such, an example of a valid identification string is

      SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>
```

It seems that this library (and ssh-keyscan) violate the spec due to the "-" in the softwareversion segment: `JSCH-0.1.54`

As Fabian points out, the "fix" will be available before SFTP GA.

Comment: Hi drew, thanks for the insights :) Just assumed the issue was on azure side since there was not a lot of detail on the original response on the Q&A site.

Comment: According to Mattias-0969 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/713024/connection-to-azure-sftp-doesnt-work-using-jsch.html they tried changing the client version to be compliant and it still doesn't work... that suggests that there is more to it than just the client version.

Comment: The problem is they are supposed to send <CR><LF> as per spec but they are only sending <LF>. The answer by @TBO highlights this.